# Package Broken, Software only partially updates

Tags: partial-upgrade

I have an issue I can't download anything, it says the package is broken but when I deleted the packages, It now only partially upgrades things, and even then it doesn't work!!!
This is what it says:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 123 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 287875 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.8.0-19-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.8.0-19-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 35: /etc/default/grub: uvesafb: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Removing linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.8.0-19-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.8.0-19-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 35: /etc/default/grub: uvesafb: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached

Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic
 linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 32 Bit.
Please be nice, I am a new to this...

Answer (score 0):

Type into your terminal `sudo apt-get upgrade -f`

The -f option should hopefully force the actions required

Comment: It didn't work, It returned E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Do you get the same error with `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic` ?

Comment: Yep, exactly the same as sudo apt-get upgrade -f